# Banderas en Git y Github

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit

Buen día

Algunos ccomandos de Git reciben banderas tal como

```
$ git commit -m "Mi Primer Commit"
```

Y entiendo que *-m* significa que le quieres pasar un mensaje o un texto

Sin embargo este no es el unico casi, otro ejemplo es

```
$ git clean -f -x -d .
```

Pero aquí no logro entender que significan esas banderas

¿Qué significan estas bandera? ¿Hay alguna pagina done pueda ver todas las banderas exitentes y en cuales comandos se aplican?

He intentado buscar pero no me aparece mucho al respecto, gracias!

Comment: Claro aqui en la documentación: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

Comment: Siempre es bueno revisar la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/docs), y para el caso específico de [clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean). A grandes rasgos lo que hace es limpiar archivos que no tengas trackeados de forma recursiva y que no estén dentro de `.gitignore`.

Comment: `git help clean` o cualquier otro comando: `git help cherry-pick` `git help rebase` `git help checkout` `git help remote` `git help merge`, etc etc